# should I still declare GOPATH?

Tags: bash, go

- I WAS reading **Learning GO** and suggest that needs to be declared on PATH
  `GOPATH="/home/user/go"`.

**this is from author:**

> it’s a good idea to explicitly define **GOPATH** and to put the **$GOPATH/bin** directory in your executable path. Explicitly defining **GOPATH** makes it clear where your Go workspace is located and adding **$GOPATH/bin** to your executable path makes it easier to run third-party tools installed via go install.

- when I run `go env` 1.18.1, is already declared, so why still suggesting declaring inside your `path` in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`

**thanks**

Comment: You should follow the instructions of the official website and disregard any contradicting information you read on any other websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [S]hould I still declare GOPATH, GOROOT?

No and **NO!**

GOPATH defaults to $HOME/go which is fine and GOPATH based builds are deprecated since several *years*. Use modules.

GOROOT never was a thing for the enduser of Go. You have to set if you work on the Go compiler itself or install Go in unusual location (which no enduser should do).

Keep away from any resource wich promotes GOPATH or even advises to mess with GOROOT.